# Cannot show information from DRF page using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, django, rest, controller, frameworks

Here are the codes that I've written:

**DRF Page** [ http://localhost:8000/index/info/?format=json ]

```
[{"id": 1, "name": "Michel", "city": "Florida", "country": "United States"}, {"id": 2, "name": "Shuvo", "city": "London", "country": "United Kingdom"}]
```

**2.html** [this is my second attempt]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="2.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in info">
            {{ x.name + ', ' + x.country }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>    
</html>
```

**2.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://localhost:8000/index/info/?format=json")
    .success(function(response) {
        $scope.info = response;
    });
});
```

My 2.html page shows NOTHING. It's completely blank. What am I doing wrong? :(

Answer (score 0):

since django and angular use the same notation to display variables, you will have to use the [verbatim tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#verbatim) for using `{{}}` as angular tags. Otherwise they will be treated as django tags.

Comment: that's not my problem.. I am not even using django templates right now.. Just trying to read JSON data from a django rest framework page with AngularJS. In fact, I would like to read data that comes in the above format like an array with no name.

Comment: are you getting your data in your Scope variable?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's something to do with the format of the data being returned in

```
$http.get("http://localhost:8000/index/info/?format=json")
```

What are you seeing in the console when http.get runs?

Here's a plunkr showing it working with your data

http://plnkr.co/edit/x0OtVbsnSMk3mdhRFEkc

Comment: You have the whole JSON data on a variable called data. And then you have assigned that variable to `$scope.info`. But I have that URL which returns that JSON data. I don't know how to put the json from that page to `$scope.info`.

Comment: Some sort of demo would be really helpful, are you getting any errors in the console? I suspect there is an issue with the data being returned. 

Have you checked out the tutorial here too: 

https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05

Comment: Are you sure that is exactly the right format the data is returned too? Whilst I've never used it according to this: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/#testing-our-api the data would be in the results object.

Comment: Kinda sure buddy. Sorry that I haven't been able to follow this post. I'm currently caught up in some Django template issues. Will get back as soon as I finish that. Btw, there are no 'results' object. It's just an unnamed array. To confirm, I have assigned the results object in .js file `$scope.info = response.results`. But no luck. :(

Comment: I think the best starting point would be checking the http get request is happening and confirming what data is returned and the format. You can do this easily in chrome using the 'Log XMLHttpRequests' in the console. Seeing this output would be very useful.

Comment: When I hit the url that I have provided in my post, I get the JSON data displayed in the browser. Doesn't that mean that the data is being returned by the API? I am struggling with capturing that data with my AngularJS script. I'm not sure if that's what u are asking though. :-/

Comment: Try running your app using Chrome web browser, open the console and watch for the http get request to see it it runs, you can then inspect that response to see exact what is coming back. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console

Comment: I've updated the plunkr example in my answer to run an http.get against some test data. If you open the console you'll see something similar to this [Screen Shot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/em6l316zytwge97/console_example.png)

Comment: Try logging the response to the console in your test app too so you can see what you get back