# Issues integrating AngularJS and Django

Tags: angularjs, django

I'm working with a friend on a web app using Django for the backend, AngularJS for the frontend, and an API written with Django REST Framework for the frontend to consume.

We're not going for a full on single page app, but inside each page we're aiming for a lot of responsivity- hence Angular + the API. The issue is that on our main template, the call to a basic Angular controller to GET some data from an API endpoint works fine. If that same code dependent on the controller is moved to a separate template accessed by a link on the main template, it no longer works. Here's the controller:

```
var matchupApp = angular.module('matchupApp', []).config(function ($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{').endSymbol('}]}');
})

matchupApp.controller("MatchupsCtrl", function ($http, $scope) {

    console.log('Hello');
    var league = 'test';
    var week = '1';


    $http.get(<api url>/?format=json).
      success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          $scope.player1 = data[0];
          console.log($scope.player1);

          $scope.player2 = data[1];
          console.log($scope.player2);


          $http.get(<api url>/?format=json).
      success(function (picks, status, headers, config) {
          $scope.pickData = picks;
          console.log($scope.pickData);
      })

      }).
      error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          // log error
      });
});
```

The two templates represent a dashboard that users see upon sign-in, and a page that shows a matchup- 2 users data displayed together. I removed the template code as I don't think it's relevant to this issue, but I can re-add if anyone wants to see it- the only difference is that the matchup template is effectively a large `<div>` so it can be loaded in without re-loading the main navbar.

The code touching the API endpoint works fine on the dashboard template, however it doesn't work at all on the matchup template.

If I insert a basic Hello World sort of text box, even that doesn't work on the matchups template:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="sometext" />

<h1 ng-show="sometext">Hello {[{ sometext }]}</h1>
```

I just see the text box with `Hello {[{ sometext }]}` below it.

The relevant url entries:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
   ...
  url(r'^dashboard', 'app.views.dashboard', name='dashboard'),
  url(r'^matchups2', 'app.views.matchups2', name='matchups2'),
   ...
```

And the basic view to call each:

```
def dashboard(request):
    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
    return render(
        request,
        'app/dashboard.html',
        context_instance = RequestContext(request,
        {
            'title':'Dashboard',
            'year':datetime.now().year,
        })
    )

def matchups2(request):
    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
    return render(
        request,
        'app/matchups2.html',
        context_instance = RequestContext(request,
        {
            'title':'Matchups',
            'year':datetime.now().year,
        })
    )
```

What are the reasons the Angular controller call to the API could be working on one page but not another? The fact that even the hello world textbox doesn't work on the matchup template makes me think there's something going on at a deeper level- my hunch is it has to do with how Django and Angular are interacting in requesting that 2nd template.

My friend and I have been looking into this for quite a while- we found [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30631195/cannot-show-information-from-drf-page-using-angularjs) with what looks like the exact issue, but I don't believe CORS applies since everything's on the same domain, and there was no accepted answer anyway.

Comment: Please post the JS traceback?

Comment: Will do, as soon as possible

Comment: @OlegTikhonov I've added `console.trace();` in my controllers.js, however when I load the 2nd template, i don't see any output to the console, even errors. Sometimes I see errors when I add the 2nd template code into the first, so I think it should be throwing some. It seems that the JS isnt even being executed

Comment: You got it @dkhaupt ? seems it is a problem of authentication

Comment: @JulioMarins I didn't end up getting this specific issue resolved- my friend and I decided to go with a single page app so that the frontend could handle everything, rather than authenticating both to the Django backend and the DRF API